# Updating to openssl 1.0.1 or greater on a very old Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS box

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, apt

I have to make sure an old rails 2.3.5 application can support TLS 1.2.

The server currently has openssl 0.9.8 installed, and I understand my first task would be to update openssl to > 1.0.1

The server is running Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS

I will take a snapshot of the VM before starting, but how risky of a upgrade is this on such a old server?

If I update openssl will it cascade into other required upgrades?

Comment: That OS is 5 years past EOL - you might be better off trying to get the application  to run on a supported OS instead (maybe by manually installing the required old ruby version there)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to risky to update the server.
Install new blank server. Than start to migrate your old software and settings.

[Don't upgrade your old Ubuntu to the new versions.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)